# Performing in a various order several methods on the objects in collection

Tags: c#, collections, foreach

The user in my application can decide which activities and in what order are to be performed for the collection of objects. The order is set at the beginning (once) for all objects.

The methods chosen by the user should be performed by the application in the correct order.

For example I have defined list of actions:

```
this.ActionsList = new List<MyAction>
{
    new MyAction {Id = "123", Order = 1, Text = "Method 5", IsActive = true},
    new MyAction {Id = "abc", Order = 5, Text = "Method 1", IsActive = false},
    new MyAction {Id = "def", Order = 3, Text = "Method 3", IsActive = true}
};
```

I also have a collection of objects:

```
var myObjects = new List<MyObjects>();
```

Now, for each object in the collection, the program must call the methods associated with activated actions. The action defined defines which method will be called.

```
foreach (var o in myObjects){

    var actions = ActionsList.Where(x => x.IsActive).OrderBy(x => x.Order);

    foreach (var a in ActionsList){
        switch(a.Id){
            case "123":
                o.Method5();
                break;
            case "abc":
                o.Method1();
                break;
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Please ignore any inaccuracies.

This solution works. However, the "switch" instruction is very large. I have dozens of such actions. This is probably not the best solution.

I think the best solution would be to indicate the appropriate method (delegates) for each object "MyAction":

```
new MyAction {Id = "def", Order = 3, Text = "Method 3", IsActive = true, 
MethodToCallDelegate = Method3}
```

I do not know how I could achieve it (or similar solution). 
I would like my code to be transparent and simple in future editions.

Comment: Have you considered making the action collection a dictionary?

Comment: Your idea is correct, it will eliminate the switch statement. Add the `Action MethodToCallDelegate;` member to `MyAction` and set it to the different methods, like `Method3`. See [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a delegate to the `MyAction` class

```
public Action<MyObjects> Action { get; set; }
```

The actions list can then be initialized like this:

```
this.ActionsList = new List<MyAction> {
   new MyAction { Order = 1, Text = "Method 5", Action = o => o.Method5(), IsActive = true },
   new MyAction { Order = 5, Text = "Method 1", Action = o => o.Method1(), IsActive = false },
   new MyAction { Order = 3, Text = "Method 3", Action = o => o.Method3(), IsActive = true }
};
```

And the actions can be applied like this

```
var orderedActions = ActionsList
    .Where(a => a.IsActive)
    .OrderBy(a => a.Order)
    .ToList();
foreach (MyObjects o in myObjects) {
    foreach (MyAction action in orderedActions) {
        action.Action(o);
    }
}
```

The trick is to use a `Action<MyObjects>` delegate accepting a `MyObjects` as parameter. This allows you to specify a lambda expression which calls a method on this object. You could even pass parameters to such methods, if required:

```
Action = o => o.StringMethod1("Hello")
Action = o => o.StringMethod2("Hello", "World")
```

or do completely different things

```
Action = o => o.Text = "okay"
Action = o => Console.WriteLine(o)
Action = o => { o.Text = "statement lambda"; Console.WriteLine(o); }
```

The delegate remains the same, because it always has one `MyObjects` parameter.

In the special case where you want to call a method that is compatible to the `Action<MyObjects>` delegate, you can pass the method itself as delegate. You omit the parameter braces to signal that you don't want to call it here.

```
Action = Console.WriteLine
```

This will have the same effect as `o => Console.WriteLine(o)` but be more efficient. Instead of calling a delegate that was created from a lambda expression that in turn calls `Console.WriteLine`, it will call `Console.WriteLine` directly. (Note, I assume that you have overridden `ToString` in `MyObjects`, otherwise this will only print the type name.)

See also: [Lambda expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#530454ef-69cf-4d92-82a5-647f455fa8f7_c)